# Keyframes or JScript for dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

My code below:

```js
function dropright() {
  var pos = 0;
  var menu = document.getElementById("menuBar");
  var t = setInterval(move, 10);

  function move() {
    if (pos >= 75) {
      clearInterval(t);
    } else {
      pos += 1;
      menu.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
  }
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
}
#container {
  width: 150px;
  height: 600px;
  left: -75px;
  position: relative;
}
#menuBar {
  width: 150px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container" onclick="dropright()">
    <div id="menuBar"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I would like to make my menubar appear from left on container click. Also I would like to make it disappear the same way. But this does nothing. Should I use JS for this or keyframes?

Comment: JavaScript for adding a class, and keyframes for animation.

Comment: How do i connect these two?

Comment: Writing a code.

Comment: @Raziasultana When you are converting into snippets, please "Tidy" it too. Thanks.

Comment: Check I have added an answer for you... And it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this way:

1. Add a class to open.
2. Use transitions, not keyframes.

**Snippet**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".dropRight").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#menuBar").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI';
}
.dropRight {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  color: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  float: right;
  margin-right: 25px;
  margin-top: 25px;
}
#menuBar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: -200px;
  width: 200px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccf;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s linear;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}
#menuBar.open {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <a href="#" class="dropRight">Open</a>
  <div id="menuBar"></div>
</div>
```

I have added a <kbd>Open</kbd> which can be used to Open or Close. `:)`

Comment: There is no need for `-webkit` etc. prefixes when using `transition`: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Just a practise. Yea, but some people still use the old web browsers. `:)` Have seen people using FF 14.

Comment: This just takes me to the site /index.html#

Comment: @SRomie Did you check the console for errors? And does it work fine in the snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to add a click listener to the element and by clicking it, adding a class. The animation can be made with CSS.

```js
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(this.className === 'shown') {
        this.className = '';
    } else {
        this.className = 'shown';
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0px;
}

#container {
    width: 150px;
    height: 300px;
    left: -75px;
    position: relative;
    background: red;
    transition: 0.3s ease left;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#container.shown {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Ha... Almost similar answer. Nice.